# Solution to a general-derivative ODE $f^{(n)}(x)=f(x)$?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

Is there a way to find / write a solution to a general from ODE $f^{(n)}(x)=f(x)$ ? For a particular $n$ it is easy, see an example for instance for $n=7$ below from Wolfram|Alpha. So it is obviously algorithmic. Any sources, reference, ideas, how to write it for a general $n$ explicitly? Thank you!

https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=f%28x%29%3D%3DD%5Bf%28x%29%2C%7Bx%2C7%7D%5D

[image]

Comment: Consider $f(x) = Ce^{\lambda x} $. You'll get a condition on $\lambda $.

Comment: ..and if you found $n$ linearly independent solutions, Bob's your uncle, since this is the dimension of the solution vector space.

Comment: @CameronWilliams and username - I have written an answer based on your comments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by @Cameron Williams in the comments - consider the ansatz ${f(x) = Ce^{\lambda x}}$. Then
$$
\Rightarrow C\lambda^n e^{\lambda x} = Ce^{\lambda x}
$$
this of course implies that ${\lambda^n = 1}$. There will be ${n}$ distinct ${\lambda}$ satisfying ${\lambda^n}$. To see this, note
$$
\lambda^n = 1 \Rightarrow \lambda^n = e^{2\pi i k }\ | k \in \mathbb{Z}\Rightarrow \lambda = e^{\frac{2\pi i k}{n}}\ |\ k \in \{0,1,\dots ,k-1\}
$$
I will label the solutions as ${\lambda_i\ |\ i \in \{0,\dots,k-1\}}$ for simplicity. Thus ${f_i(x) = C_ie^{\lambda_i x}}$ are a set of $n$ linearly independent solutions to the ODE, and hence we can be sure that is all of them by what @username said also. The ODE is linear, and so the most general solution is given by the sum:
$$
f(x) = C_0e^{\lambda_{0} x} + \dots + C_{k-1}e^{\lambda_{k-1} x} = C_1e^{\lambda_1 x} + \dots + C_{k-1}e^{\lambda_{k-1} x } + C_{0}
$$
(since ${\lambda_0 = 1}$). As desired.